# How we can get forest data directory in MarkLogic

Tags: java, rest, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to get the forest Data directory in MarkLogic. I used the following method to get data directory...using the Server Evaluation Call Interface running queries as admin. If not, please let me know how I can get forest data directory

```
ServerEvaluationCall forestDataDirCall = client.newServerEval()

  .xquery("admin:forest-get-data-directory(admin:get-configuration(), admin:forest-get-id(admin:get-configuration(), \"" + forestName +"\"))");

for (EvalResult forestDataDirResult : forestDataDirCall.eval()) {
  String forestDataDir = null;
  forestDataDir = forestDataDirResult.getString();
  System.out.println("forestDataDir is " + forestDataDir);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation yet? https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:forest-get-data-directory

Comment: I'm also curious why you want to know the data directory? Your application should not care, and if for admin purposes, you have admin ui, and ops director you could use.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I used same X query to get data directory.I missed "import module namespace admin="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy"; in above code .How can I add this namespace to above code.We need to get Data directory as per my requirement.

Comment: Just add the import clause to the query string you send across. You can send a full XQuery statement, not just single lines..

Comment: I was facing issue while adding import clause to the above query ..can you suggest me how to form import clause to the above query request

Answer (score 5):

I see no reason for needing to hit the server evaluation endpoint to ask this question to the server. MarkLogic comes with a robust REST based management API including getters for almost all items of interest.

Knowing that, you can use what is documented here:

[http://yourserver:8002/manage/v2/forests](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/forests)

Results can be in JSON, XML or HTML

It is the getter for forest configurations. Which forests you care about can be found by iterating over all forests or by reaching through the database config and then to the forests. It all depends on what you already know from the outside.

References:

[Management API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management)

[Scripting Administrative Tasks](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api)